# How to say "Little did I/he/she/they know"?

Tags: words, translation, set-phrases

I found a few examples at ALC, but still not sure about the best way to say it.

Comment: Although it is difficult to translate a short phrase and make sure that all parts of the phrase appear in the translation... How about 彼には分からなかったのは or 彼には分からなかったことは?

For any given sentence with `little did he know, ...`, there is bound to be a better translation, which does not use this phrase, though, so I am not sure how useful it is.

Comment: I agree with @user1205935.  彼にわからなかったことは is usually quite translationese, but it is probably the best you can do without looking at the other part of the sentence.  Translating word-to-word (or phrase-to-phrase) is not the best way to translate a sentence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example, the most natural way of translating this expression

> One day Jennifer tidied up her son's bedroom.  Little did she know her son would be so mad when he found that out.

can be rephrased simply as follows:

> One day Jennifer tidied up her son's bedroom.  She did not know her son would be so mad when he found that out.

Basically it is a fancier way of saying ～ことをまったく知らなかった where ～ is the statement that follows the expression.

I find the most natural way of translating this is to write 彼女は（息子が怒り出す）とは思わなかった, to show that the person was kind of caught off guard by what happened.